# Concat causes stack overflow if called multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, linq, concatenation, stack-overflow

Application accidentally crashed with stack overflow error. After research I found that the reason of crash is following code:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    result = result.Concat(item.Data);
}
```

This is concatenation of multiple `IEnumerable`s. Application crashed when `items` contained 10,000 elements.

`SelectMany` fixed this issue. But still...

Why `Concat` extension causes stack overflow here?

Comment: Once again: if I could teach everyone just one thing about LINQ it would be that *the result of a query expression is an object which can execute the query*, not *the results of executing the query*.

Comment: Also see the Schlemiel-the-painter section of  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky. You have implemented the deferred-execution version of this algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that the result of `Concat` is not a collection - it's a *query*.

So your "result" is effectively

```
Enumerable.Concat(item10000.Data, 
                  Enumerable.Concat(item9999.Data, 
                                  ....
                                    Enumerable.Concat(item2.Data, 
                                                      item1.Data))));
```

When the nested queries are generated it causes a stack overflow.

Another option would be to create a list and add to it each time:

```
var list = new List<something>();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    list.AddRange(item.Data);
}
```

Which is essentially what `SelectMany` does (but with a deferred enumerator, not a `List`):

```
result = items.SelectMany(item => item.Data);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you ask the 10,000th concat to get its result it'll ask the 9,999th concat operation for *its* result, with the intention of yielding a few more values after it's done, and then then 9,999th concat operation will ask the 9,998th concat for its result, which will ask the 9,997th concat for its result, and eventually you either get down to the 1st concat, or you run out of stack space.

As you mentioned right in the question, `SelectMany` is the correct operation to flatten a sequence of sequences.