# Enumerable.Concat not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Below is the code:

```
string[] values = Acode.Split(',');
IEnumerable<Test> tst = null;

foreach (string a in values)
{
    if (tst== null)
        tst = entities.Test.Where(t=> (t.TCode == Convert.ToInt16(a)));
    else
        tst.Concat(entities.Test.Where(g => (g.TCode == Convert.ToInt16(a))));

}

return tst.ToList();
```

I am not able to get all the records in tst, it is giving me records only for the last value in array.

So if my array contains 1,2,3,4 I am getting records only for the 4. Whereas i need all the result for 1,2,3 and 4 get appended in tst.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're not using the result of `Concat`. Did you mean `tst = tst.Concat(...)`?

Comment: I know this is old but it's worth mentioning, Abuse of the Concat method might blow your stack.
In many places I've read that the LINQ expressions return an object that can run the query to get the desired result. (I would've commented instead of answering but I don't have the reputation yet)
Here's some links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065930/concat-causes-stack-overflow-if-called-multiple-times http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/how-enumerableconcat-brought-down-a-production-server.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Concat` doesn't modify anything - it returns a new sequence, which you're currently ignoring.

However, rather than using `Concat`, you should just use `SelectMany` to flatten the sequence:

```
string[] values = Acode.Split(',');
return values.SelectMany(a => entities.Test.Where(t => t.TCode == Convert.ToInt16(a)))
             .ToList();
```

Or more efficiently, convert `values` into a `List<short>` and then you can do *one* query:

```
List<short> values = Acode.Split(',').Select(x => short.Parse(x)).ToList();
return entities.Test.Where(t => values.Contains(t.TCode)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

That is because `Concat` will return a new instance of your enumerable.

Either use in your else :

`tst = tst.Concat(...)`

Or Change your Enumerable into  list from the beginning :

```
string[] values = Acode.Split(',');
List<Test> tst= new List<Test>;

foreach (string a in values)
{
    tst.AddRange(entities.Test.Where(g => (g.TCode == Convert.ToInt16(a))));
}

return tst;
```

Comment: I'll just add here that trying to convert an string to an int without checks or exception catching can be dangerous if the user has access to this value one way or another